# Gaussian distribution with mean and sigma in C++11

Tags: python, c++11, gaussian

I am trying to get gaussian distribution with mean and sigma in C++11. I have been successful at converting Python to C++ but I have a doubt about the way I am initializing the random generator. Do I need to call random_device() and mt19937() inside the call to get a distribution or can I just call them once statically and re-use those all the time? What is the cost of leaving the code as it is?

```
# Python

# random.gauss(mu, sigma)
# Gaussian distribution. mu is the mean, and sigma is the standard deviation.

import random

result = random.gauss(mu, sigma)


// C++11

#include <random>

std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 e2(rd());

float res = std::normal_distribution<float>(m, s)(e2);
```

Comment: What's a Gaussian distribution *without* mean and sigma?!

Comment: C++'s `<random>` separates engines (which produce randomness) from distributions (which produce statistical samples). `e2` is your engine; your distribution is a temporary.

Comment: `random_device()` is only used to seed the engine. You could set the key otherwise (e.g. from a well determined number, if you care about reproducibility.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two parts of the algorithm:

- uniform random number generator,
- and convert the uniform random number to a random number according to Gaussian distribution.

In your case, `e2` is your uniform random number generator given the seed `rd`, `std::normal_distribution<float>(m, s)` generates an object which does the 2nd part of the algorithm.

The best way to do it is:

```
// call for the first time (initialization)
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 e2(rd());
std::normal_distribution<float> dist(m, s);
// bind the distribution generator and uniform generator
auto gen_gaussian = std::bind(dist, e2);

// call when you need to generate a random number
float gaussian = gen_gaussian();
```

If you don't care about which uniform random number generator to use, you can use `std::default_random_engine` instead of `std:mt19937`.

Comment: What does the std::bind() function do in that case? Does it just return a generator function (functor?) that I can invoke later on? Thank you.

Comment: @JohnDifool It's unspecified -- See [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) for more information.